# Link restbed with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, restbed

In trying to link restbed with CMake I get the usual undefined function error. However, trying the exact same code linked with `g++ test.cpp -o test -lrestbed` works fine.

Furthermore, when I first implemented the CMakeLists.txt it also worked fine and as I added to the project it started facing issues. Now even a single restbed function is not defined.

My restbed includes are located at `/usr/local/include` and the shared objects to link at `/usr/local/lib`. Pretty standard locations.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(vcar-server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -lrestbed")

file(GLOB CXX_EXEC "src/*.cpp")

add_subdirectory(vcar-embedded)

add_executable(vcar-server ${CXX_EXEC})
target_link_libraries(vcar-server vcar)
```

Comment: `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are the C++ *compiler* flags. Add libraries with `target_link_library`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, or rather use it as a "last resort" when configuring the build system as a user. Prefer to use object model in place of global variables. The modern cmake way would most probably be something along:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(vcar-server)
add_subdirectory(vcar-embedded)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
add_executable(vcar-server ${cxx_exec})
target_link_libraries(vcar-server PUBLIC vcar restbed Threads::Threads)
set_target_properties(vcar-server PUBLIC CXX_STANDARD 20)
```